# MySQL query optimization improvement

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello all I have a MySQL query that fetches data from more than on tables. Here is my query

```
SELECT 
                user_id as id,
                user_name as name,
                user_phone as phone,
                user_email as email,
                user_address1 as address1,
                user_address2 as address2,
                user_city as city,
                user_state as state,
                user_country as country,
                user_available as available,
                user_location as location,
                user_latitude as latitude,
                user_longitude as longitude,
                user_description as description,
                user_company as company,
                user_gender as gender,
                (SELECT MIN(service_price) FROM service WHERE service.user_id = a.user_id) as price,
                (SELECT service_recomanded FROM service WHERE service.user_id = a.user_id ORDER BY service.service_price ASC LIMIT 1) as recomandad,
                verified_email,
                verified_facebook,
                verified_phone,
                verified_twitter,
                (SELECT providerphoto_name FROM providerphoto WHERE providerphoto.user_id = a.user_id ORDER BY providerphoto_order ASC LIMIT 1 ) as photo,
                (SELECT ROUND( AVG(review_rate),2) FROM review WHERE review.user_id = a.user_id ) AS rate,
                (SELECT service_ICOC FROM service WHERE service.user_id = a.user_id ORDER BY service_price ASC LIMIT 1) as type
             FROM 
                user a
            WHERE a.user_type = 'provider' 
                AND a.user_active=1 
                AND a.user_deleted=0
```

It gets data from user table, service table, review table and providerphoto table. It works too but the execution time is very slow. I guess to make it a single query and avoid the inner five queries may run it fast. Any help?

Table structures.

```
--
-- Table structure for table `providerphoto`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `providerphoto` (
  `providerphoto_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `providerphoto_file` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `providerphoto_name` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `providerphoto_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `providerphoto_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`providerphoto_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `providerphoto` (`user_id`,`providerphoto_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=487 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `review`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `review` (
  `review_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `review_title` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `review_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `review_content` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `review_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `review_rate` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `review_tip` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `service_booked` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`review_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `review_date` (`review_date`),
  KEY `review_user_id` (`review_user_id`),
  KEY `review_rate` (`review_rate`),
  KEY `review_tip` (`review_tip`),
  KEY `service_booked` (`service_booked`),
  KEY `review` (`user_id`,`review_rate`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=97 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `service`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `service` (
  `service_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `service_name` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `service_created_by` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `service_ICOC` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `service_price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `service_date_added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `service_date_expire` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `service_time` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `service_rate` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `service_type` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '1-in call, 2-out call, 3-in&out call',
  `service_recomanded` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `service_genre` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `service_message` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`service_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `service_ICOC` (`service_ICOC`(255)),
  KEY `service` (`user_id`,`service_price`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=854 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `user`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_name` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_password` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_email` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_phone` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_address1` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `user_address2` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_city` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_state` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_country` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_company` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_birthday` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_register_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_type` enum('provider','client') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_available` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `verified_email` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `verified_facebook` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `verified_phone` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `verified_twitter` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_facebook_friends` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_twitter_friends` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_longitude` decimal(10,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
  `user_latitude` decimal(10,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
  `user_deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_gender` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_facebook_token` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `user_location` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_push_notification_token` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_timezone_diff` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `balanced_uri` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_reset_passwd_token` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `is_test_user` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  KEY `deleted_idx` (`user_deleted`),
  KEY `email_idx` (`user_email`(255))
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=426 ;
```

Comment: If you want us to help optimize a query, **you need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com ASAP.

Comment: Did you try using `LEFT JOIN` for those tables instead adding as subqueries in the SELECT?  Also provide the details of indexes and number of records in the tables.

Comment: @AndyLester this query gets results so the first thing is sure that the tables have the indexes and the 2nd thing is the row count in the user table is 321, review table 115 service table 723 providerphoto table 239 and each of these tables has user_id as foreign key for associating with user table.

Comment: @devdesign: "this query gets results so the first thing is sure that the tables have the indexes" is not a correct conclusion.  Queries will execute just as accurately whether or not indexes exist or not.  It's just a matter of how the SQL query planner must decide to do the work.  If there are no indexes, or incorrect indexes, then the query will have to walk the entire table to get the data, but it *will* get the data.

Comment: Again I say: Please show us the table and index definitions, not paraphrases or summaries.  It's entirely possible that you're missing and index you didn't know about, or that you've defined an index or column incorrectly, but we can't tell without seeing the definitions of the table and indexes.  We are glad to work with you if you work with us as well.

Comment: @Slowcoder can you suggest a query with LEFT JOIN to avoid the inner queries?

Comment: @AndyLester I have updated my question with adding the table structure please take a look if you can help from this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can probably just add indexes to speed up the query.  Try adding the following indexes:

```
service(user_id, service_price)
providerphoto(user_id, providerphoto_order)
review(user_id, review_rate)
```

Comment: I have altered tables and added these indexes but it does not work.

Comment: @devdesign . . . I find that surprising.  I would comment out the five subqueries and then add them in one at a time to determine where the performance problem is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this.  This will return all the values for the users as I did not use the `ORDER` and `LIMIT` in the query.  This is just for the approach.

```
SELECT 
            a.user_id as id,
            user_name as name,
            user_phone as phone,
            user_email as email,
            user_address1 as address1,
            user_address2 as address2,
            user_city as city,
            user_state as state,
            user_country as country,
            user_available as available,
            user_location as location,
            user_latitude as latitude,
            user_longitude as longitude,
            user_description as description,
            user_company as company,
            user_gender as gender,
            MIN(s.service_price) as price,
            s.service_recomanded as recomandad,
            verified_email,
            verified_facebook,
            verified_phone,
            verified_twitter,
            pp.providerphoto_name as photo,
            ROUND( AVG(r.review_rate),2) as rate,
            s.service_ICOC as type
         FROM 
            user a LEFT JOIN service s on s.user_id = a.user_id LEFT JOIN providerphoto pp on pp.user_id = a.user_id LEFT JOIN review r on r.user_id = a.user_id 
        WHERE a.user_type = 'provider' 
            AND a.user_active=1 
            AND a.user_deleted=0;
```

Comment: This returns only a single row. However if I remove the MIN and ROUND(AVG) from the fields it returns 200 records and faster than the original query with inner SELECT queries but the records are short of 38 rows as the original query returns 238 queries which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is index `user.user_type`, `user.user_deleted` and `user.user_active` to let the optimizer quickly start with a smaller set of `user` records to have to deal with.

Do you mean to allow `service.user_id` to be NULL?  That seems like a mistake.

Also you may want to throw indexes on any columns where you're doing an `ORDER BY`.

The best way to find out what is slow in this query is to do a EXPLAIN QUERY and analyze what it tells you.  We can help you with that as well.

Comment: No service.user_id cant be null. Can you please write query you think will be best?

Comment: The best way to find out what is slow in this query is to do a EXPLAIN QUERY and analyze what it tells you. We can help you with that as well.